# Laravel return file not found even I have it

Tags: laravel, storage

I developing with laravel and before this all are working fine but this week, laravel always return `file not found` even I have it in storage. Why this happen? 
 [Error from laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIPWK.png) .[My file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOTX5.png)

```
public function file()
    {
        $file= asset('storage/documents/President New Year Message 2019 (Text only).pdf');

        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        ];

        return response()->download($file, 'President New Year Message 2019 (Text only).pdf', $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Can you try this asset(str_replace(' ', '%20', ''storage/documents/President New Year Message 2019 (Text only).pdf''))

Comment: same error sir. `file not found`

Comment: you probably want a file path not a url to a file

Comment: Can explain further sir. Using the `asset()` return path instead of url right?

Comment: If you used the Laravel File Storage system to store the file (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls) you can get the file with `Storage::url('file.jpg');`. I wouldn't recommend writing the whole URL in your code, since can quickly come back to haunt you when you have more files or multiple locations to save them.